# Spark: How to overwrite data in partitions but not the root folder while saving to disk?

Tags: apache-spark

W.r.t. following code:

```
spark.sql(sqlStatement).write.partitionBy("city", "dataset", "origin").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(rootPath)
```

It deletes everything under the `rootPath` before writing data to it. If the code is changed to:

```
spark.sql(sqlStatement).write.partitionBy("city", "dataset", "origin").mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(rootPath)
```

then it does not delete anything. What we want is a mode that will not delete the data under `rootPath` but delete the data under a `city/dataset/origin` before writing to it. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try basepath option. Partition discovery will be only pointed towards children of  '/city/dataset/origin'

according to documentation -

> Spark SQL’s partition discovery has been changed to only discover partition directories that are children of the given path. (i.e. if
>   path="/my/data/x=1" then x=1 will no longer be considered a partition
>   but only children of x=1.) This behavior can be overridden by manually
>   specifying the basePath that partitioning discovery should start with
>   (SPARK-11678).

```
spark.sql(sqlStatement)\
.write.partitionBy("city", "dataset","origin")\
.option("basePath","/city/dataset/origin") \
.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(rootPath)
```

let me know if this doesnt work. I'll remove my answer.

Comment: it doesn't work. Your answer uses SaveMode.Append but I tried it with SaveMode.Overwrite assuming that was a typo in the answer.

Comment: Yeh , i think i copied append line from your post instead on overwrite. But I guess SPARK-11678 applies only for read options may be. You can ask spark user mailing list to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode="dynamic"` setting, which was introduced in Spark 2.3.0.

Comment: Does not seem to make a difference.